# Problemas al acceder a otro disco con python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

Hola a todos les pido ayuda con un problema que tengo en python y en linux (en ubuntu), estoy haciendo un programa que todos los proyectos que tenga en una carpeta (en este caso '/var/www/html') los mueva a otro disco despues de 30 días que no haya alterado una carpeta, no estoy seguro si mi programa funciona bien, pero hasta ahora todo funciona como espero, este es mi código:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import shutil
import time
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

html_dir = '/var/www/html/'
disk_dir = "/media/david/Main/old_projects"

dirs = os.listdir(html_dir)

for dir_or_file in dirs:
    if os.path.isdir(html_dir + dir_or_file):
        datetime = datetime.strptime(time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(html_dir + dir_or_file)), '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y') + timedelta(days=30)
        now = datetime.now()

        if datetime <= now:
            shutil.move(html_dir + dir_or_file, disk_dir)
```

Por cierto "/media/david/Main/" es la dirección del disco, y "/media/david/Main/old_projects" es la carpeta donde quiero guardar los proyectos viejos, eso funciona bien, pero solo funciona si "monto el disco", me refiero a que todo funciona cuando abro la aplicacion "Files" y me meto al disco, despues de eso me sale que el disco esta montado, en cambio si despues de apagar mi computadora la enciendo, e intento ejecutar el programa me sale esto:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 814, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/www/html/hola' -> '/media/david/Main/old_projects'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/move", line 19, in <module>
    shutil.move(html_dir + dir_or_file, disk_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 830, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, copy_function=copy_function,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 565, in copytree
    return _copytree(entries=entries, src=src, dst=dst, symlinks=symlinks,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 466, in _copytree
    os.makedirs(dst, exist_ok=dirs_exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 215, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 225, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/david/Main'
```

Y la idea es que este programa se ejecute solo, usando `cron`, por lo que no se como hacer que eso pueda funcionar siempre, espero me puedan ayudar, desde ya gracias :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas que se monte tu disco automaticamente.

Primero saca el id o el device de tu disco con `lsblk`.

Conecta y ejecuta `lsblk`. Desconecta el disco y corre de nuevo `lsblk`.

Te va a aparecer algo asi como `/dev/sdb1` como el valor que cambia. Ese es el device de tu disco externo.

Agrega tu disco al archivo `/etc/fstab`.

El formato de `fstab` es el siguiente:

```
#device        mountpoint             fstype    options  dump   fsck

/dev/sdb1    /media/david/Main        ext4    defaults    0    1
```

Tambien fijate en el tipo de systema de archivos. En este ejemplo yo puse `ext4` pero tu pon el tuyo.